# Append div to all elements in document

Tags: jquery, variables, append, each

I would like to append a div to all elements in the document. The div should have the same `height` and `weight` of the element to which they are being appended. To get the `height` and `width` I set a var like this:

```
var height =   $(this).height();
var width =   $(this).width();
```

And append like this:

```
$('*').append('<div class="over" style="height:'+height+';width:'+width+';">'+height+' + '+width+'</div>');
```

As you can see in this [Fiddle(LINK)](http://jsfiddle.net/d4k6g/) Its not really working out. Its giving me the same dimensions `251 + 420` which is weird because none of the elements have these dimensions.

How do I append the `div.over` to all `(*)` elements in the document and have its dimensions set to the element they are being appended to? ( Do I have to use `.each`? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will be solution:

```
$('body *').each(function(){
    var t = $(this), w = t.width(), h = t.height();
    t.append('<div class="over" style="height:'+h+'px;width:'+w+'px;">'+h+' + '+w+'</div>');
});
```

Comment: same problem..the div.over does not get the dimensions of the element its being appended on

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the height/width of each object, not just once. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4k6g/10/)

```
$('body *').each(function (i, v) {
    var $this = $(this),
        h = $this.height(),
        w = $this.width();
    $this.css({ height: h, width: w * 2 });
    $this.append('<div class="over" style="display:block; height:' + h + 'px !important;width:' + w + 'px !important;">' + h + ' x ' + w + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: But the span is 200 + 50, not 132 + 419 as it is showing in your code

Comment: @Youss I updated my example. You have to double the width if you want to see just as much of the original before the append. I also had to add `!important` to the `"over"` div to override the width defined by the css. If you don't want to see the original and just want to see the overlay only remove the `* 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function syntax for `append()` like so:

```
$('body *').append(function(){ 
    var height = $(this).height(),
        width  = $(this).width();

    return '<div class="over" style="height:'
            +height+';width:'+width+';">'+height+' + '+width+'</div>'; 
});
```

**Note:** I've changed your selector as otherwise you'd be looping over element such as the `<head>`, which would likely cause random irregularities.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwf5H/).

Comment: Thanks, its still not totally working but at leat I get the dimensions. The "over" div should get the dimensions of the element its being appended to. For instance: the span has 200 + 50 so the div.over which is being appended should have 200px + 50px as well...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$('body *').each(function(i,el){
    var height = $(el).height();
    var width = $(el).width();
    $(el).append('<div class="over" style="height:'+height+';width:'+width+';">'+height+' + '+width+'</div>');
});
```

Edit: you should target everything within the body, not just everything otherwise you get a div outside of the body tags.

Comment: Same problem here, the span has different dimensions

Comment: @Youss That is not the span div, that is the one placed at the `body` tag (it is different for me as I have a different screen resolution). See my edit to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all elements with the each function.

```
$('*').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).append('<div class="over" style="height:'+$(element).height()+';width:'+$(element).width()+';">'+$(element).height()+' + '+ $(element).width()+'</div>'); 
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/d4k6g/4/

Comment: The div "over" should span across the elements, as it is now it does not cover the elements by there "width" and the span has different dimensions